# SQL running balance calculation for a partition group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement of capping the Qty to certain level. The below data is partitioned and row numbers also provided. Please refer below this is the current data in table

[image]

However output should come like this. Please refer below.

[image]

The current truck capacity is 16 Qty. But if you see the total Allocation Qty at partition level is 17. So we need to minus that extra 1 Qty from the Final Allocation Qty dynamically at Row level preferable from Rownumber 1..2..3 like that. I had tried to do running total using while loop but no luck

### What I have tried to so far

```
DECLARE @GroupCount INT
SET @GroupCount = (SELECT MAX(PartitionNum) FROM Allocation_Table) 
DECLARE @RowCount INT

-- Declare an iterator
DECLARE @I INT,@J int
 --Initialize the iterator
SET @I =1


WHILE (@I <= @GroupCount)
BEGIN
SET @RowCount = (SELECT MAX(RowNumber) FROM Allocation_Table WHERE PartitionNum=@I)  
DECLARE @BS float=0
SELECT @BS = cast([Remainder Qty to be dropped] as float) FROM Allocation_Table WHERE PartitionNum=@I 
SET @J = 1

WHILE (@J <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
        
--PRINT @I

declare @BV float, @Qty float,@flg bit,@Ibs float, @EV float

SELECT @Qty=[Final Allocation Qty] FROM Allocation_Table WHERE PartitionNum=@I and RowNumber=@J 
set @IBS=@BS
SET @BS=case when (@BS>=@Qty) then  @BS-@Qty  else @BS end

SET @flg=case when (@IBS>=@Qty) then  1  when (@IBS<@Qty) and @IBS>0 then  1 else 0 end

set @BS= case when (@IBS<@Qty)  then 0 else @BS end 

update Allocation_Table set BS_Cal=@BS ,Flag=@flg WHERE  RowNumber = @J and PartitionNum=@I 


SET @J = @J + 1
END
SET @I = @I + 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this kind of aggregation with a windowed (and partitioned) aggregate, you'd need to use iteration; most likely with a rCTE.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: How did you get that `Final Allocation Qty` of `4,9,4` in the first place ? why not get it correct in the first place rather than doing a fix later

Comment: @Squirrel - Unfortunately that cannot be corrected in the first place. That Qty is what system suggests. But we need to cap it based on Truck Capacity

Comment: @DaleK Posted the code which I have tried so far

Comment: Why not put a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the column then, @Satyajit , so that a value greater than the other column can't be inserted?

Comment: you nee to provide more case scenario. Like what if `Remaining Qty to be dropped` is 2 or higher, how do you want to update the `Final Allocation Qty`. Also must you reduce row 1 first or you can reduce the row with highest `Final Allocation Qty` ? Any other consideration or constraints ?

Comment: @Squirrel Row 1 to be reduced first after that row 2..3 like that. 
Remaining Qty to be dropped=[sum of Final Allocation Qty at Partition level]-[Truck Capacity for the partition]
In this case 17-16=1. So 1 has to be minus from 1st row. If 1st row Final allocation Qty is 0 then it would go to the next row and minus.

If the remaining Qty is 3(For example) , then 1 will be minus from 1st row. And 2 will be minus from 2nd row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what has been said in the comments this is very possible using window functions, it is just a little convoluted.

Assuming I have understood your situation correctly, you want to remove items from the `material` in order of their `RowNumber` until the `Truck capacity` is reached.  To do this just required some running aggregates and conditional maths based on the value in the previous row:

## Query

```
declare @t table(pn int,rn int,Material varchar(100),Allocation int,Capacity int);
insert into @t values
 (1,1,'abc',4,16)
,(1,2,'bac',9,16)
,(1,3,'cab',4,16)
,(2,1,'abc',4,12)
,(2,2,'bac',9,12)
,(2,3,'cab',4,12)
,(3,1,'abc',4,2)
,(3,2,'bac',9,2)
,(3,3,'cab',4,2)
,(4,1,'abc',14,112)
,(4,2,'bac',19,112)
,(4,3,'cab',14,112)
,(5,1,'abc',140,112)
,(5,2,'bac',19,112)
,(5,3,'cab',14,112)
;

with d as
(
    select *
          ,sum(Allocation) over (partition by pn) as TotalAllocation
          ,sum(Allocation) over (partition by pn) - Capacity as TotalOverage
          ,sum(Allocation) over (partition by pn)
            - Capacity
            - sum(Allocation) over (partition by pn order by rn)
            as Overage
    from @t
)
select pn
      ,rn
      ,Material
      ,Capacity
      ,TotalAllocation
      ,Allocation
      ,case when Overage > 0
            then 0
            else case when lag(Overage,1) over (partition by pn order by rn) is null
                      then case when Allocation < (Allocation - TotalOverage)
                                then Allocation
                                else Allocation - TotalOverage
                                end
                      else 
                            case when lag(Overage,1,0) over (partition by pn order by rn) > 0
                                      then Allocation - lag(Overage,1,0) over (partition by pn order by rn)
                                      else Allocation
                                      end
                      end
            end as AdjustedAllocation
from d
order by pn
        ,rn;
```

---

## Output

| pn | rn | Material | Capacity | TotalAllocation | Allocation | AdjustedAllocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc | 16 | 17 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | bac | 16 | 17 | 9 | 9 |
| 1 | 3 | cab | 16 | 17 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | abc | 12 | 17 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | bac | 12 | 17 | 9 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | cab | 12 | 17 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | abc | 2 | 17 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | bac | 2 | 17 | 9 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | cab | 2 | 17 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | abc | 112 | 47 | 14 | 14 |
| 4 | 2 | bac | 112 | 47 | 19 | 19 |
| 4 | 3 | cab | 112 | 47 | 14 | 14 |
| 5 | 1 | abc | 112 | 173 | 140 | 79 |
| 5 | 2 | bac | 112 | 173 | 19 | 19 |
| 5 | 3 | cab | 112 | 173 | 14 | 14 |

Comment: Thank you good Sire @imdave This works perfectly. Much obliged